# Select next badge contains ugly formatted text

Tags: feature-request, design, badges

I’m not a designer, but I think this looks ugly in terms of graphic design:

> [image: Next 100+ badges]

There should be at least some kind of indent/alignment according to table view of the page.

Comment: Why ugly? Looks just fine to me. You can say same way any page and anything on SE is ugly. (i.e. that's 100% personal view.)

Comment: I little padding wouldn't hurt.