# Invalid message in "Select your next badge" popup

Tags: bug, design, badge-progress

Consider the "Select your next badge" popup. You can access it via [user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current):

> [image: user profile]

In some cases, i.e. filtering tags by class (Gold only on the image below) the following message is invalid:

> showing top 100 of 142 available badges; please use the search box to find a specific badge

There are no badges at all on the current tab, hence text should be omitted, or rephased according to the count of currenlty visible items.

> [image: Next gold badge]

Comment: I see. This text is only visible if you have more than 100 tag badges available. When choosing a different tab, this text never changes.

Comment: Related question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306609