# Track badge with conditional views that require improvement

Tags: feature-request, badges, mobile-web, tag-badges, badge-progress

This behaviour was seen in Android 10 using both Firefox version 81.1.5 and Google Chrome version 86.0.4240.99 and in multiple communities.

---

In one's profile, in the Activity tab, there are at least two main sections with similar functionalities that enable tracking badges:

1. Activity>Badges
2. Activity>Reputation

In Activity>Reputation, if we change the tab to Gold/Silver,

[image]

As you can see there's some informative text. This informative text will only appear in certain communities depending on whether or not one has Q&As in more than 100 tags (or it looks to be intended that way). This particular behaviour was previously reported:

- [Tag badge tracker - "showing top 100 of x available badges" text is in the wrong position](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354690/5675325)
- [Tag badges "showing top 100 of 201 available badges..." when fewer badges shown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308697/5675325)
- [Invalid message in "Select your next badge" popup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313990/364217)
- [Select next badge contains ugly formatted text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306609/364217)

For me (considering I don't yet have a bronze tag badge) it doesn't make sense to show up in Gold/Silver tabs as it is not displaying any badge (this wasn't yet reported in the linked questions); also in the Bronze tab the text also appears in the bottom making it harder to see than if it was in the beginning with a nicer style (see the next image).

[image]

---

It would be helpful to have either some valid text (as it is empty, unnecessary or in a hard to spot location) or the future badges, in the sections Gold and Silver when choosing which badge to track (for instance, being able to select gold `Python` tag even though one hasn't yet earned the bronze or the silver). Both are helpful. I see the future badges more helpful for long term thinking, as it happens in the section Activity>Badges>Choose which badge to track. Mortarboard (Bronze) is related with Epic (Silver) and then Legendary (Gold) which varies only in the amount of times one needs to earn a specific amount of reputation.

Comment: Perhaps you could crop your images to only show the relevant section next time.

Comment: @Luuklag it was a way to validate that it was really in that community.

Comment: In that case one large screenshot would suffice. In this way it is hard to read your question. I tried with a smaller size images, but that makes the text within them illegible.

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you actually ask here. As others already said, the images are HUGE, and the text itself is well hidden somewhere between them. Screenshots should be **addition** to bug report or feature request, not the report/request itself.

Comment: Also, please make your title specific. What about the “behaviours”? What is the issue? I want to know what your question is about just by looking at the title.

Comment: [Related](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com+"showing+top"+"available+badges") (for some reason, these reports are mostly posted on MSO rather than MSE): [Tag badge tracker - "showing top 100 of x available badges" text is in the wrong position](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354690/4642212), [Invalid message in "Select your next badge" popup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313990/289905), [Tag badges "showing top 100 of 201 available badges..." when fewer badges shown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308697/4642212).