# Markdown help page should include information on how to resize images in a post

Tags: feature-request, markdown, images, help, image-size-modifiers

In all of the communities, there's a similar [Markdown help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help/#images). I'm in particular interested in the images section.

Very often when writing Q&As, especially from mobile, users take advantage of images. Also, it is common that then someone needs to edit the images due to them being too big ([it happened to me the other day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355829/362304)).

Considering [there's a way to resize them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25051/364217), can we include that information there too?

Comment: That resizing is only possible after uploading.