# «modified 19 mins ago user» yet I can't see any modification done by the user

Tags: bug, questions, suggested-edits, top-questions

When looking at the Top Questions

[image]

can see that in the question with the title "Include in Markup help information on how to resize images in a post" it says

> modified 19 mins ago 2.Hallac 1

Yet, when I open [the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356091/364217) there's nothing in it that the user `2.Hallac` has done.

This might be related to my account not having permissions to visualize suggested edits that are not done in my account; yet, if that's the case, it makes sense that I shouldn't see that this particular user made an edit (assuming that's the case).

Comment: Also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54867/how-is-this-user-causing-activity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user has a deleted answer to that question. These turn up as "modified" in the main page but are not visible under 10k

Comment: Right... shouldn't that be hidden too for users under 10K?

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 technically the question became active, so it "earned" its spot in the list. If you hide it you wonder why it became active. I don't think the question should become inactive due to that. No matter what, you convey info that reveals something was deleted (specially if you visit that Q/A). What is the problem with showing that info?

Comment: @rene I'm ok with that, thanks!

Comment: @rene well, if you can't see what happened maybe just hide the name of the user, e.g. have just "modified 19 minutes ago", without saying who modified. Still bit confusing, but at least no "false info".

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard yeah, but it matters if that was modified by a 1-rep user or not. 1-rep is often not worth clicking, > 1 rep often  means something relevant happened, even on deleted posts. But meh, not worth dev time in the next 6 to 8 weeks I would say.

Answer (score 4):

That user created an answer and then deleted it. As you don't have 10K rep, you can't see the deleted answer.

Once the user creates the post the question is then listed as modified on top questions. Deleting that post does not reset that modification date for anyone. The action happened it's just you can't see it any more.